# Summation of a Random Variable

Tags: algorithm-analysis, probability-theory

I'm having trouble grokking Cormen's *Algorithms* book on pg. 120.  The context is the [hiring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) (as it is called in the book). Here is the part that is tripping me up:

> "Let X be the random variable whose value equals the number of times we hire a new office assistant."

and later on:

> "...we let $X_i$ be the indicator random variable associated with the event in which the $i$th candidate is hired ... [so that] $X = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n$"

In particular, Cormen defines $X_i$ as follows:

$$
  X_i = 
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if candidate $i$ is hired} \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$

**Question:** Why does $X = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n$?

First, this equation only makes sense if $X$ and each of the $X_i$ have the same domain. Here I'm assuming the domain of $X$ is $\{1,2, \ldots , n\}$ (i.e., each number representing the number of assistants hired).

That implies that the domain of each $X_i$ must be $\{1,2, \ldots , n\}$. Then it seems that, i.e., $X_2$ will satisfy $X_2(2) = 1$ and be $0$ everywhere else.

But if that's the case, then $X_1 + \ldots + X_n$ will satisfy $X(i) = 1$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots , 6\}$, which means that $X \ne X_1 + \ldots + X_n$ (since, for example, $X(2) = 2$). What am I missing?

**EDIT:** The more I think about it, the more I'm convinced that my misunderstanding lies with the way $X$ itself is defined. Is it true that i.e. $X(2) = 2$?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "$X(2)$". $X$ is defined as an integer-valued random variable, not a function.

Comment: A [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition) is a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your outcomes are not the number of candidates but rather which candidates were hired: $\Omega = \{0,1\}^n$. Then you have $X_i(a_1, \dots, a_n) = a_i$ and $X(a_1, \dots, a_n) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i(a_1, \dots, a_n) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i$.

Comment: What is $\Omega$ in this context: is it the domain, or the range of the random variable $X$ (or of $X_i$)?

Comment: Omega is usually used as the symbol for the possible outcomes, i.e. the variable domain.

Comment: Do you mean by $\{0,1\}^n$ the set $\{(0,1) \times \ldots \times (0,1) \}$ (with cardinality $2^n$)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. You can also see it as an n-dimensional vector.